# What's the space complexity of this permutations algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, permutation

The time complexity of this algorithm to compute permutations recursively should be `O(n!*n)`, but I am not 100% sure about the space complexity.

There are `n` recursions, and the biggest space required for a recursion is `n` (space of every permutation * `n!` (number of permutations). Is the space complexity of the algorithm` O(n!*n^2)?

```
static List<String> permutations(String word) {
    if (word.length() == 1)
        return Arrays.asList(word);
    String firstCharacter = word.substring(0, 1);
    String rest = word.substring(1);
    List<String> permutationsOfRest = permutations(rest);
    List<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>(); //or hashset if I don’t want duplicates
    for (String permutationOfRest : permutationsOfRest) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= permutationOfRest.length(); i++) {
            permutations.add(permutationOfRest.substring(0, i) +  firstCharacter + permutationOfRest.substring(i));
        }
    }
    return permutations;
}
```

Comment: Anything with n! is O(scary) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the space complexity is "just" O(*n*! × *n*), since you don't simultaneously hold onto all recursive calls' `permutationsOfRest` / `permutations`. (You do have two at a time, but that's just a constant factor, so isn't relevant to the asymptotic complexity.)

Note that if you don't actually *need* a `List<String>`, it might be better to wrap things up as a custom `Iterator<String>` implementation, so that you don't need to keep all permutations in memory at once, and don't need to pre-calculate all permutations before you start doing anything with any of them. (Of course, that's a bit trickier to implement, so it's not worth it if the major use of the `Iterator<String>` will just be to pre-populate a `List<String>` anyway.)

Comment: Your stack call is as big as O(n), for 4 characters string you will have 4 recursive calls at the bottom, which is O(n). But we don't multiply it, we summarize it, so we get O(n!*n + n). But O(n!*n) dominates O(n), so we drop O(n), and this gives us O(n!*n). Recursion is not a constant factor here, it is less dominant.

Comment: @VladimirBuskin: The "constant factor" that I referred to is 2, because you keep **two** of the lists in memory at any given time, where each of those lists requires up to O(*n*! × *n*) space.